# Why does ubuntu 11.10 freeze when playing video?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, freeze, hdmi, video-player

I run ubuntu 11.10 on i5 CPU with 4GB RAM
nvdia geforce GTS 250 connected to widescreen tv (HDMI)

When using vlc, xbmc or boxee to play movies the system randomly freeze, the audio is looping the last words of the video file and nothing is responding.
So I have to manually reset the system.
Can anybody help?

P.S. I forgot to mention the the log file was full of line regarding xbox 360 wireless receiver (I dual boot with windwos 7) so I unplugged it to see if that counts

Comment: Do you run proprietary Nvidia driver? Is there anything in logs of xserver? /var/log

Comment: I have no linux near right now. =[

Comment: @PocketSam Yes I do run nvidia drivers (from restricted driver repo). I really don't understand much about logs. In xorg.0.log I see some errors about drivers (it seems to load all of them). Anyway since I unplugged the xbox360 controller wireless receiver it did not crash... I don't know whether that's or not.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use SMPlayer from software center i had Freezes on my PC when playing video but they magically stopped when i started